# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error when free method is called

Tags: c, arrays, free

I m trying to free the memory space for an array of char:

```
        static void cleanArray(char* array)
                {
                    int i;
                    int size = strlen(array) + 1;
                    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        free(array[i]);
                    free(array);
                }

    int main(){
    char* array = (char *)malloc(1 * sizeof(char*));
    int c;
    for(c=0;c<100;c++){         //code to populate some string values in the array.
    void *p = realloc(array, (strlen(array)+strlen(message)+1)*sizeof(char*));
    array = p;
    strcat(array, "some string");
    }

cleanArray(array);           //I get error only when I call this method.
    }
```

But for the above code I m getting `Segmentation fault` error.

And when I just try the following code instead of cleanArray() I dont think the array is freed up:

```
    free(array);
printf("%s",array); //it prints all the values in the array. Hence, I concluded it is not freedup.
```

Answer (score 4):

Line `free(array[i]);` in loop have problem. `array[i]` is a char value(which is actually int by integer promotion) and passing that value to `free` will be considered as pointer. Now you are trying to free that address about which you do not have any idea.

Comment: Hmm got it. Thanks. But simply free(array); will suffice? I am worried that after free(array); if I printf("%s",array); I am able to print all the characters which I added previously. Please suggest.

Comment: `free` doesn't delete all the content which was allocated. It will be re-used for some other operations. It just means, that part of memory(which was dynamically allocated) is released back so that others can use it. And, your current process doesn't own it from now on.

Comment: @Arun i would like to suggest you to compile with strict warning level and you can see all the possible bugs which are leading towards `seg fault` in your code.

Comment: I am currently compiling this way:   gcc -W -Wall -O2

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

1. You don't need to call `free()` on each character of the string. Just call `free(array)`.
2. `sizeof(char*)` in `malloc()` and `realloc()` is incorrect.

Comment: +1.  Also, `strlen(array)` gives undefined results on the first call and `strlen(message)` is wrong unless `message` has the same length as `"some string"`

Comment: @NPE: I followed the first point. But if I put a printf(array) after free(array), I am still able to see all the characters printed again... For second point, can you please suggest me the correct way.

Comment: @simonc: I checked with test data. It is gives the count of the characters inside the array.